# How to dynamically parse python string templates?

Tags: python, string, templates

I have a string with some placeholder in it like:

```
url = "http://www.myserver.com/$abc/$foo_or_bar/$xy"
```

I cannot use Templates (http://is.gd/AKmGxa), because my placeholder-strings needs to be interpreted by some logic.

I need to iterate over all exisiting placeholders and replace them by a code-generated value.

How can I do this? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) which can accept replacement function as a second argument;

```
>>> url = "http://www.myserver.com/$abc/$foo_or_bar/$xy"
>>>
>>> def some_logic(match):
...     s = match.group()  # to get matched string
...     return str(len(s) - 1)  # put any login you want here
...
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\$\w+', some_logic, url)
'http://www.myserver.com/3/10/2'
```

BTW, [`string.Template`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) also can be used if you pass custom mapping:

```
>>> class CustomMapping:
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         return str(len(key))
...
>>> import string
>>> url = "http://www.myserver.com/$abc/$foo_or_bar/$xy"
>>> string.Template(url).substitute(CustomMapping())
'http://www.myserver.com/3/10/2'
```